# Trouble implementing vue js with Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade, vuejs2

I have created a character counter for SEO input fields with Vue JS. It worked perfectly in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bantawa04/na24x196/) but when I implemented it with Laravel. It isn't working. It doesn't give any error, it shows

`NaN characters remaining.`

where it should show numbers of characters remaining.

My code in jsfiddle which works perfectly in jsfiddle.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
   <label for="title">SEO Description</label><br>
        <textarea v-model="seo_description" value="{{seo_description }}" maxlength="156">
        </textarea>
   <p>Characters remaining:@{{ maxlength-seo_description.length }}</p>
</div>
new Vue({
   el: "#app",
   data: {
   maxlength: 156,
   seo_description: ''
   }
});
```

My code in laravel view:

```
<div id="app">
    <label for="title">SEO Description</label><br>
        <textarea name="keyword" v-model="keyword" class="form-control meta" maxlength="255">
        </textarea>
        <p>@{{ maxlength-keyword.length }} characters remaining.</p>
</div>
<script>
var keyword = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    maxlength: 255,
    keyword: ''
  }
});
```

I tried by copying my code into jsfiddle and run, it works perfeectly there. But it doesn't run with laravel.

Comment: Side note: You should really consider making `charactersRemaining` a `computed` property.

Comment: I haven't installed gulp nor I have linked vue js to my laravel . I have freshly installed laravel. My vue js dev tool chrome extension detected vue js. So I didn't think I should link vue js  to this laravel.

Comment: @ceejayoz It does work that way in fiddle but doesn't run with laravel why ???????????

Comment: install gulp, and then run gulp watch, and on a different terminal run php artisan serve

Comment: Try implement this to your Laravel App http://jsbin.com/hiwulabayu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @ZacharyDale try adding ready(): { console.log(this.keyword);  } to Vue, to see what's going on...

Comment: Actually its working for me?

Comment: You haven't installed gulp nor included cdn?

Answer (score 0):

This should be the Problem

```
value="{{seo_description }}"
```

You are not escaping it for vue.js. You should either do

```
value="@{{seo_description}}"
```

or

```
:value="seo_description"
```

AND you really need to add seo_description to your data. Always init the default data - even if the value is empty.

However you do not need this at all actually. Since you bound the value to the model already.

Last remark: I think you should always wrap your vue.js outputs like

```
<p>@{{ maxlength-keyword.length }} characters remaining.</p>
```

into elements

```
<p><span>@{{ maxlength-keyword.length }}</span> characters remaining.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

in laravel 5.3 vue js has been put into.default together with jquery.

try to remove app.js or main.js from your main layout or master layout or whatever layout and that time you can use vue instance per blade now.

make sure to include first vue js dependency from home layout